# Browse object for loop on specific class

Tags: javascript

I try to browse object values. This object come from a form and it like that :

```
object[0]
     ...
     0  button.btn.btn-default.btn-number
     1  button.btn.btn-default.btn-number
     2  input.input-text.qty.text attribute value = "5"
     3  button.btn.btn-default.btn-number
     4  input.input-text.qty.text property value = "9" attribute value = "8"
     5  button.btn.btn-default.btn-number
     6  input#_wpnonce attribute valuet = "568e08e95b"
```

I need to browse this object and make the sum of value only for this class

> input.input-text.qty.text

Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, could you clarify? And add the code you are having problems with and explain what is not working. Also you might consider document.getElementsByClassName https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: I want in this example, to make a loop on this attributes `input.input-text.qty.text` for make a sum of values.